# linux subversion error while running 'svn' command

Tags: ubuntu, putty

when I am running $ svn command I am getting an error like:

> svn: error while loading shared libraries: libsvn_client-1.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Please anyone can suggest me how to slove the above issue.

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be a problem with your subversion installation. Assuming you used `apt-get` to install subversion, run the following commands to reinstall it:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove --purge subversion
$ sudo apt-get install subversion
```